# Verificar se intervalo de horario está dentro de outro intervalo

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

Preciso saber se foi trabalhado dentro de um intervalo fixado

```
$entrada_padrao = strtotime('08:00');//fixo como parametro
$saida_padrao = strtotime('18:00');//fixo como parametro

$entrada_trabalho = strtotime('09:00');//apontamento no relogio de ponto
$saida_trabalho = strtotime('20:50');//apontamento no relogio de ponto
```

Neste exemplo tem que me retornar TRUE

Já tentei esta lógica abaixo, mas não funciona porque tanto ele pode entrar antes de **$entrada_padrao** quanto pode sair após **$saida_padrao** ou ambos

```
if(($entrada_trabalho <= $entrada_padrao) && ($saida_trabalho >= $entrada_padrao)){
    echo "True";
}else{
    echo "False";
}
```

Comment: qual o "intervalo fixado"? `$entrada_padrao` ou `$entrada_trabalho`? fiquei na dúvida em relação a isto, no entanto, sugiro que você [**edite**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/523809/edit) sua pergunta e especifique isso. Antes de mais nada, veja como criar um [mre].

Comment: editado, a entrada_padrao e saida_padrao é fixo como padrao. O usuario  apontará o horario trabalhado e irei comparar se ele trabalhou dentro do horario padrao, independente da hora que ele entrou ou saiu

Answer (score 1):

No caso, deve retornar true apenas se ele chegar antes ou no horário de início e sair no horário de fim ou após. Nesse caso, a entrada de trabalho deve ser menor ou igual a entrada padrão. Enquanto a saida trabalho deve ser maior ou igual a saida padrão. Deve-se fazer essa correção.

```
$entrada_trabalho <= $entrada_padrao && $saida_trabalho >= $saida_padrao
```

Answer (score 0):

Temporariamente montei esta solução

```
$valor = 100;//valor a pagar de bônus
$entrada_padrao = strtotime('08:00');//fixo como parâmetro
$saida_padrao = strtotime('18:00');//fixo como parâmetro

$entrada_trabalho = strtotime('09:00');//horário de entrada no trabalho
$saida_trabalho = strtotime('19:50');//horário de saída no trabalho


function calcBonus($ep, $sp, $et, $st, $v){
    if ($et >= $ep && $et <= $sp) {//se entrou dentro do horário padrão
        return $v;
    }else
    if ($et < $ep && ($st <= $sp && $st >= $ep)) {//se entrou antes do horário padrão, saiu antes da saída padrão mas não antes da entrada padrão
        return $v;
    }else
    if ($et < $ep && $st > $sp) {//entrou antes da entrada padrão e sai após o horario padrão
        return $v;
    }else {
        return 0;
    }
}

var_dump(calcBonus($entrada_padrao,$saida_padrao,$entrada_trabalho,$saida_trabalho,$valor));
```

Se o período trabalhado estiver passado dentro do período padrão ele me retorna o valor a pagar.
Sugestões de melhorias também são bem vindas.